# Does Revelation 10:11 belong in chapter 10 or chapter 11?

Tags: greek, revelation

Does the original greek language (or other concrete evidence) provide an indication that Revelation 10:11 belongs in chapter 10, or does it it lack such an indication, such that it is ambiguous in the greek?

The point of my question is that, is there objective evidence that would prevent a scholarly debate on where the paragraph marker is.

***NOTE:*** Should the paragraph division be debatable, it raises a question of what is the theological implication. however it might be a bit too subjective to ask on stack exchange, perhaps it would be interesting to hear thoughts in comments?)

Comment: You realize that chapter and verse divisions are a later addition and most English Bibles use the system created by Robert Estienne for his 1551 edition of the Greek New Testament :).

Comment: Thanks @jonathan, that's correct, my question is specifically about the Greek and if it affirms this division

Answer (score 1):

There a couple things I would point towards. Firstly, The context of chapter 11 seems to start a new idea separate from chapter 10. Verse 11 could possibly go on the start of chapter 11. The second thing would be the use of kai at the start of chapter 11, indicating a new sentence (keep in mind this same indicator starts verse 10:11). So, objectively, without any refutation, no. Based on transnational experience, yes, a paragraph there is warranted.